# Why does my temple only give one content citizen instead of two?

Tags: civilization-2

I have a size 4 city on Diety level. I'm early in my empire (obviously, my capital is only size 4) so I do not have very many cities. A city this size at this stage should have one content citizen, and the rest unhappy. If I look at my 'happy tab', I confirm this is the default state.

However, it shows that my temple makes one of them content, and my warrior makes another content via martial law (I'm a Monarchy). This leaves me with one unhappy citizen, which without any happy citizens **puts my capital into civil disorder!**. Yikes!

Upon reading the text of a temple, it states it makes "Up to two unhappy citizens content". I've never run into this before where it had leftover unhappy citizens without using both of its "up to two". Why is this happening?

Screenshot of city info:[image]

Comment: Good question, good to see someone's still playing Civ 2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Temple improvement makes two citizens content - but only *after* you've researched Mysticism.  Before this research is complete, they'll only make one citizen content.

Also note that building the Oracle wonder doubles this "content citizen" bonus.

Comment: Over a decade of playing this game, and I have never noticed that snippet. Sure enough, "increases the effectiveness of temples". Because I always race to Philosophy, especially on the harder levels, Mysticism happens pretty quick for me, so I've actually never run into this before. This particular capital had much more food than trade unfortunately, so it grew faster than I could keep up. Doh!

Comment: @corsiKa, yeah, this is weird and counter-intuitive to be certain.  At least they could call it out in the description of the temple...  but whatever :P